# How to change time complexity, having nested loop?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, nested-loops

I have a python code for my task, which do well, but time complexity is bad and i don't know how to change it. The task:

*Given two arrays of integers, "a" and "b," each of length "n," you need to find the number of index pairs "i" and "j" such that the inequality is satisfied:
aᵢ ⊕ aʲ ≥ bᵢ ⊕ bʲ.
Note that in this problem, if "i" is not equal to "j," then the pairs (i, j) and (j, i) are considered distinct. The symbol ⊕ denotes bitwise addition modulo 2, or the XOR operation.*

```
n = int(input())
a = list(map(int, input().split()))
b = list(map(int, input().split()))

count = 0

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if a[i] ^ a[j] >= b[i] ^ b[j]:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

Any suggestions to improve the runtime?

Comment: First: What do you think the runtime complexity of your code is? Then what should your code do? Then what may be alternative algorithms to achieve this (and what's their  runtime complexities)?

Answer (score 1):

Improved the efficiency of code using Numpy.
Comparison :

- Your code for 10K entries on a and b, run time: 0:00:46.925000
- Code based on NumPy for 10K entries on a and b, run time: 0:00:00.453003 i.e., almost 100 times faster

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

n = 10000
a = [1,2,3,4,5,16,17,18,19,20] * int(n/10)  # List with 10 K items created for testing
b = [10,9,8,7,6,11,12,13,14,15] * int(n/10)  # List with 10 K items created for testing

print("Len a : ", len(a))
print("Len b : ", len(b))

######### Your Code Test ######################
count = 0
print("Starting your code test")
start = datetime.datetime.now() # Start time
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):        
        if a[i] ^ a[j] >= b[i] ^ b[j]:
            count += 1

end = datetime.datetime.now() # end time
delta = end-start 
     
print("Your code time delta : ", delta)
print("Result : ", count)


############## New Code test #######################

count = 0
print("Starting new code test")
start = datetime.datetime.now() # Start time

a_arr = np.array(a).reshape(-1,1)
a_arr_biwise = np.bitwise_xor(a_arr, a_arr.transpose())  #bitwise XOR of array on itself

b_arr = np.array(b).reshape(-1,1)
b_arr_biwise = np.bitwise_xor(b_arr, b_arr.transpose())  #bitwise XOR of array on itself

comparison_matrix = np.greater_equal(a_arr_biwise,b_arr_biwise) # axor >= bxor comparison on each position.
count = comparison_matrix.sum() # find True count , i.e. where >= is True

end = datetime.datetime.now() # end time
delta = end-start      

print("New code time delta : ", delta)
print("Result : ", count)
```

> output

```
Len a :  10000
Len b :  10000
Starting your code test
Your code time delta :  0:00:46.925000
Result :  80000000
Starting new code test
New code time delta :  0:00:00.453003
Result :  80000000
```

Can see that the result is the same for both codes.

Answer (score 1):

1. since xor is symmetric: a[i] ^ a[j] == a[j] ^ a[i] (and the same for b) so you can reduce the inner loop to j>i.
2. Since a[i] ^ a[i] >= b[i] ^ b[i] is always true, you can also skip this cases.

This will not improve the complexity O(n²) but at least double the speed.

```
     n = int(input())
     a = list(map(int, input().split()))
     b = list(map(int, input().split()))

     count = n  // the cases i==j always fulfills the condition a[i] ^ a[j] >= b[i] ^ b[j]:

     for i in range(n):
         for j =0; j<i; j++ :
             if a[i] ^ a[j] >= b[i] ^ b[j]:
                 count += 2

     print(count)
```